# Can anyone suggest me how to solve bypass in one cell in moving soldiers around in grid game?

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-engine, game-physics

Can anyone suggest me how to solve bypass problem in moving soldiers around ? I have grid liek game ( rows=200, columns=200 ) and I can send soldier around and find path with A* algorithm ( one soldier occupy approximately on quarter of cell ). My problem is when I send two soldiers on trip on map and they can cross during the trip in on cell, how to by pass them ? At the moment they acting like ghosts and pass one through other. Did anyone have same task in past ?

Comment: Yes, many have had this problem in past. How about mark the block the soldier is on as not walkable and checking the next step if block i want to enter is still walkable if not, i have to recompute the path.

Comment: Can't you just make one soldier politely wait for the other one to pass by?

Comment: @jrok: what if the other one decides to make camp on that square?

Comment: What's wrong with a sequential approach? For each step do 'calculate S1 path - move S1 - calculate S2 path - move S2'? In this case you shouldn't have this problem as the calculate S2 shouldn't take that square in account as it is occupied because of move S1. edit: this certainly not the 'best' approach (that depends on your requirements) but likely one of the easiest.

Comment: @KillianDS Too intensive for processor, if you have lot off soldiers and peasants and big map

Comment: @Damir: for any decent path finding in a dynamic game you probably need a recalc at some time. You can possibly make this trigger only if you find there is someone in the way as an optimization.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a very simple form of [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection). You want to see whether two units collide, i.e. would intersect/be in the same grid cell in the next time step. There is a bunch of strategies. Start with the link and read your way through the net ;)

Comment: Yes the problem is related to collision, as the OP already said. The question is how to handle it with regards to pathfinding.

Comment: @tenfour: well, the OP didn't mention the term so I figured it might be helpful to name it. Sometimes that's what it needs when you're stuck.